# Residence permit expires while travelling

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, eu, resident-permit, austria

I live and work in Austria.  I need to travel from Austria to England for a meeting (and come back).  However, my Austrian residence permit will expire during my stay in England.  I will apply for an extension of my residence permit well in advance, but from my previous experience, I will not be allowed to collect my new residence permit before the old one expires.

Will this cause any trouble to my journey in any way?  In particular, will I be refused to board either of the flights?  And will I be denied entry to England or Austria?  If this situation turns out to be problematic, then is there a solution to the problems?

In case it matters, my passport allows me to stay in the EU visa-free for 90 days, and it is likely that by the time I travel to England, I will have a notification letter (in German) from the Austrian authorities stating that the extension of my residence permit is approved.

It would be great if there are websites of authorities that I can show the airline/immigration officer in case of an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being eligible for visa-free entry in the Schengen area is a huge help here. Travelling for up to 90 days after the expiry of your residence permit is perfectly kosher so airlines should have no issues with it, *even if you did not have any plan to renew your residence permit*. This also means you should not need any proof that your renewal application has been approved either. First-hand reports and legal details can be found on the [travel sister site](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/does-tourist-visa-90-days-apply-after-a-working-holiday-visa-ends-in-schengen?lq=1).

Once you reach Austria, I would show the letter and/or expired permit to the border police to avoid being treated as a visitor. I am not sure whether you are supposed to get an entry stamp or not, it might help you avoid it (although it would not be a big deal either way for a *bona fide* resident).

Comment: Thank you very much.  So presumably, I will be treated as a "tourist" when travelling back to Austria.  Am I expected to have a plan for an onward journey then?  I am worried that I may be asked to present one by the airline/immigration officer.

Comment: I am not sure whether other people will be treated the same, but I was not asked by anyone about any plan for an onward journey.  Although I did offer the approval letter for my residence permit extension, the immigration officer in Austria did not look at it, and I got a stamp on my passport.